# Javascript performance consideration. Is dot operator faster than subscript notation?

Tags: javascript, performance

Is dot operator faster than subscript notation?

```
var obj = {x: '5'};
obj.x = 'some value';
obj['x'] = 'some value';
```

Comment: It would help to have this code in context with other code, then consider the penalties in ratio to the other code.  If some functionality was really deemed unnaturally slow it is very often removed from the language (an example is `with` being deprecated)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not anything incredibly worrying.  Acessing variables by `window` or `eval` are significantly slower though.

http://jsperf.com/dot-vs-square-bracket/5

Comment: You forgot to write that accessing by variable is 10x slower! (`obj[x]` = ...) This is probably because the JIT compiler can pre-search the string if it's a constant and so it becomes "equivalent" to the dot notation, but if the string is in a variable the JIT can't optimize it and has to do it at runtime.

Answer (score 8):

This is maybe outdated information, but it is a statement affecting at least older Safari versions.
From O'Reilly's [Writing Efficient JavaScript](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html):

> For most browsers, there is virtually no difference between using dot
>   notation for object property access (data.count) and bracket notation
>   (data["count"]). The one exception is Safari, where bracket notation
>   is significantly slower than dot notation. This holds true even for
>   Safari 4 and later using the Nitro JavaScript engine.

Looks like http://jsperf.com/ has been taken down -- it says `Website Disabled`, but using an embedded WebKit engine from Qt4 it looks like that this statement is true, using this test:

```js
var t = new Date().getTime();
var x = { c: 123 };

for (var i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
    x['c'] += 2;

document.write(( new Date().getTime() - t ) + '; value ' + x.c);
```

```js
var t = new Date().getTime();
var x = { c: 123 };

for (var i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
    x.c += 2;

document.write(( new Date().getTime() - t ) + '; value ' + x.c);
```

Using `x['c']` took about 4 seconds while `x.c` ran for about 3 seconds.
Current Firefox and Chrome appear to make no distinction between the two.

Comment: True! The difference is quite notable when iterating on a humongous dataset.