# Can bracket notation be used to compress/obfuscate JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, compression, minify, uglifyjs2

This is mainly for academic reasons, but I'm curious as to whether there is anything wrong with *extensively* using bracket notation over dot notation.

Some possible applications may include:

- further compression by deduplication of commonly used methods or properties
- further obfuscation by making de-minified code still hard to understand/follow

I understand that gzip compression may render the benefits of deduplication useless and obfuscation of JavaScript may be futile, hence I'm really just curious about the pros or cons of this technique for academic purposes.

Consider taking this code through the following series of transformations:

```
(function () {
    var parent, child;
    parent = document.body;

    child = document.createElement('div');
    child.setAttribute('foo', 'bar');
    parent.appendChild(child);
    parent = child;

    child = document.createElement('div');
    child.setAttribute('foo', 'bar');
    parent.appendChild(child);
    parent = child;

    child = document.createElement('div');
    child.setAttribute('foo', 'bar');
    parent.appendChild(child);
    parent = child;

    child = document.createElement('div');
    child.setAttribute('foo', 'bar');
    parent.appendChild(child);
    parent = child;

    child = document.createElement('div');
    child.setAttribute('foo', 'bar');
    parent.appendChild(child);
    parent = child;

    child = document.createElement('div');
    child.setAttribute('foo', 'bar');
    parent.appendChild(child);
    parent = child;

    child = document.createElement('div');
    child.setAttribute('foo', 'bar');
    parent.appendChild(child);
    parent = child;

    child = document.createElement('div');
    child.setAttribute('foo', 'bar');
    parent.appendChild(child);
    parent = child;
})();
```

1. Generate "constants" for accessing methods:

   ```
   var createElement = "createElement";
   var setAttribute = "setAttribute";
   var appendChild = "appendChild";
   ```
2. Replace dot notation calls with bracket notation calls using those constants

   ```
   child = document[createElement]('div');
   child[setAttribute]('foo', 'bar');
   parent[appendChild](child);
   ```
3. Now a mangler can reduce the variable names and method calls to single characters

   ```
   var c = "createElement";
   var s = "setAttribute";
   var a = "appendChild";

   child = document[c]('div');
   child[s]('foo', 'bar');
   parent[a](child);
   ```

After minification, this contrived example achieved a 44% reduction in size.

Obviously this is not something that to be done manually; it should probably be done against the AST against the more commonly used properties/methods.

Is there anything with using bracket notation across the board?

I've found some SO questions saying they are [pretty much the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291964/javascript-performance-consideration-is-dot-operator-faster-than-subscript-nota), while some claim bracket notation involving a variable lookup cannot be JIT optimized and is much slower. And then there are [microbenchmarks](http://jsperf.com/dot-vs-square-bracket/5) that kind of show both, so I'm not really sure where it really stands.

I do know that [UglifyJS2 compressor options](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress) optimize property access by default, doing the inverse: converting bracket notation to dot notation. I just don't know the reasoning behind it, unless it's really just to save 3 extra characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does indeed cause JIT issues on some engines. A [much simpler benchmark](http://jsperf.com/simple-dot-vs-brackets) that doesn't conflate a dozen things demonstrates this (below). So you *can* do it, but you have to accept the performance cost, which is significant on some engines (reduces property access speed by ~64% on Chrome, for instance; **~86%** on IE11, in my simple test below).

Prep:

```
var obj = {};
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    obj['prop' + i] = 'value ' + i;
}
var name = "prop257";
```

Testing `obj.prop257`:

```
if (obj.prop257 !== "value 257") throw "Error in test";
```

Testing `obj[name]`:

```
if (obj[name] !== "value 257") throw "Error in test";
```

Results of runs on Chrome, Firefox, IE11:

[image]

On both Chrome (V8) and IE11 (JScript), performance is radically reduced. Firefox (SpiderMonkey) is impacted, but not as badly.

Comment: Very interesting. I added a third test case for bracket notation with a static string instead of a variable lookup. In Chrome it seems to have performance similar to dot notation, which proves the JIT optimization (and lack thereof when a variable lookup is involved). Interestingly other browsers (I tried Safari) may not perform this optimization, so that would explain the reasoning behind UglifyJS's property access optimization as well. Thanks!

Comment: @DrSammyD: What's "better" about it?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder You are forcing the reevaluation of the variable. He's talking about constant variables at the root scope for accessing purposes, you need to maintain their constancy to not introduce var reevaluation for every access.

Comment: Some crazy optimized Firefox messed up my results for browser comparison. This one is better http://jsperf.com/bracket-v-dot-2

Comment: @DrSammyD: My example doesn't add any reevaluation his doesn't. What do you think does?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Oops, I read your test wrong. I thought the for each was inside the benchmark not the setup.